# error using htlatex and no output file is generated :(

Tags: errors, tex4ht, warnings, html, dvi-mode

I am very new to using LaTeX so please be kind :)

Specs: Using Windows OS, TexLive, Overleaf(initially). Used the accessible package from https://libguides.lib.msu.edu/c.php?g=995742&p=8207771

Situation: I am working on a math-based accessibility template in LaTeX. My tex file was made on Overleaf and has no errors. I have downloaded this file as a zip, extracted it and am now trying to convert this tex file into an HTML file so that screen readers can read it more easily(compared to PDFs). I am using TexLive on a Windows OS to do the conversion.

Problem: I am using  `htlatex LaTeX_Accessible_Template.tex` in the TexLive cmd line but no output file is being generated. I have tried looking into the log file but have had no luck googling the warnings/errors.

Question: Can someone please help me decipher the log file and figure out what I am doing wrong? I've included both my template and my log file in the google drive below:

The main issue I think is with these lines in the log file:

```
! pdfTeX error (\pdfobj): not allowed in DVI mode (\pdfoutput <= 0).
<recently read> \pdfobj

l.68 \pdfobj
             reserveobjnum%
No pages of output.
Transcript written on LaTeX_Accessible_Template.log.
----------------------------
tex4ht.c (2023-10-13-15:32 kpathsea)
tex4ht LaTeX_Accessible_Template.tex
  -i/tex4ht/ht-fonts/
  -ewin32/tex4ht.env
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `LaTeX_Accessible_Template.dvi'
--- error --- Can't find/open file `LaTeX_Accessible_Template.dvi'
----------------------------
t4ht.c (2018-07-04-14:25 kpathsea)
t4ht LaTeX_Accessible_Template.tex
  -ewin32/tex4ht.env
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env)
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `LaTeX_Accessible_Template.lg'
```

Comment: Welcome! You've got some code in your `.tex` file which is specific to PDF, but you're compiling to DVI. What's on line 68 of your source? Can you produce a minimal document which reproduces the problem? Then you can post the code here. People may be reluctant to access a random file on a stranger's Google drive. If you really can't create a minimal example, you can find a list of pastebin sites at https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/List_of_applications#Pastebin_services. I tend to use `0x0.st`, but there are several options.

Comment: Hey @cfr! My line 68 in the .tex file is as follows: ``` \item Avoid using nested tables, blank cells or merged cells.```. For context, I am trying to make a bullet list which is followed by a table.

Comment: Are you able to convert a bullet list without a table?  Are you able to convert a paragraph without a bullet list?  Either of those should be about 20 lines.  And please copy/paste the error message instead of posting a screen shot.

Comment: Hey @Teepeemm! Yes I can convert a bullet list without a table. I can convert a paragraph without a bullet list. Made the changes to the question to include error as text.

Comment: The advice in your link are wrong. The accessibility package does not produces valid, tagged pdf. The author explicitly discourage the use: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/accessibility. The \axessibility should not be used either. It has not been adapted to the development in the tagpdf package. If you want a tagged PDF you should try the code from the LaTeX tagged PDF project. If you want an html simply remove the accessibility package.

Comment: Taking a step back, I find it strange that you need an accessibility package for htlatex.  Isn't a big selling point of html output that it's accessible?  What does the accessibility package add?  What is htlatex's output lacking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ulrike said, the `accessibility` package is the culprit. It explicitly uses some PDFTeX primitives, which cause fatal error in LaTeX in DVI mode, which is used by TeX4ht.

Here is a configuration which should prevent this fatal error. It is a bit complicated, so you may want to wait until the fix is included in TeX Live, which should be soon.

We need multiple configuration files to get this working. First is `usepackage.4ht`:

```
% usepackage.4ht (2023-11-10-15:20), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2003-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2023 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2023-11-10-15:20}

   \def\:temp{tex4ht}\ifx \:temp\@currname
   \:warning{\string\usepackage{tex4ht} again?}
   \def\:temp#1htex4ht.def,tex4ht.sty#2!*?: {\def\:temp{#2}}
\expandafter\:temp \@filelist htex4ht.def,tex4ht.sty!*?: %
\ifx \:temp\empty  \else
   \:warning{if
    \string\RequirePackage[tex4ht]{hyperref} or
    \string\usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref} was
    used try instead, repectively,
    \string\RequirePackage{hyperref} or
    \string\usepackage{hyperref}}
\fi

\fi
\gdef\a:usepackage{\use:package ,!*?: }
\gdef\use:package#1,{%
   \if :#1:\def\:temp##1!*?: {}\else
      \def\:temp{#1}\ifx \@currname\:temp
             \def\:temp##1!*?: {\input usepackage.4ht  }%
      \else \let\:temp=\use:package \fi
   \fi \:temp}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{titlesec.sty}{titlesec-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{biblatex-chicago.sty}{biblatex-chicago-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{cleveref.sty}{cleveref-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xr.sty}{xr-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xr-hyper.sty}{xrhyper-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{eso-pic.sty}{esopic-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{showframe.sty}{showframe-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{expl3.sty}{expl3-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{savetrees.sty}{savetrees-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{newcomputermodern.sty}{newcomputermodern-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{newcomputermodern.sty}{newcomputermodern-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fontawesome5-utex-helper.sty}%
{fontawesome5-utex-helper-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fontawesome5.sty}{fontawesome5-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{biblatex.sty}{biblatex-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xeCJK.sty}{xecjk-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{unicode-math.sty}{unicode-math-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{ctex.sty}{ctex-hooks.4ht}
\AddToHook{class/ctexart/before}{\input{ctexart-hooks.4ht}}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{luatexja.sty}{luatexja-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{luatexja-fontspec.sty}{luatexja-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{polyglossia.sty}{polyglossia-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fontspec.sty}{fontspec-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{tikz.sty}{tikz-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{pdfbase.sty}{pdfbase-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{pdfx.sty}{pdfx-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{lua-widow-control.sty}{lua-widow-control-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{tagpdf.sty}{tagpdf-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{accessibility.sty}{accessibility-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{embedfile.sty}{embedfile-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{breakurl.sty}{breakurl-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{hyperref.sty}{hyperref-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{bookmark.sty}{bookmark-hooks.4ht}
\AddToHook{package/tabu/before}{\RequirePackage{tabularx}}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{caption.sty}{caption-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{footnotebackref.sty}{footnotebackref-hooks.4ht}
\AddToHook{package/doc/before}{\SUPOff}
\AddToHook{package/doc/after}{\SUPOn}
\AddToHook{package/hypdoc/before}{\SUPOff}
\AddToHook{package/hypdoc/after}{\SUPOn}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{mathtools.sty}{mathtools-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{babel.sty}{babel-sty-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{minted.sty}{minted-sty-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{graphics.sty}{graphics-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{graphbox.sty}{graphbox-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{xcolor.sty}{xcolor-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{imakeidx.sty}{imakeidx-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{fancyhdr.sty}{fancyhdr-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{exerquiz.sty}{exerquiz-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{hyperxmp.sty}{hyperxmp-hooks.4ht}
\Configure{PackageHooks}{datetime2.sty}{datetime2-hooks.4ht}


\endinput
```

This file declares configuration files which should be loaded before LaTeX packages. The configuration file for accessibility, `accessibility-hooks.4ht`, can look like this:

```
% accessibility-hooks.4ht (2023-11-10-15:20), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2023 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2023-11-10-15:20}

% redefine commands that would cause fatal error when the package is being processed
\let\:origpdfobj\pdfobj
\let\:origpdfoutput\pdfoutput
\let\pdfoutput\@undefined
\def\pdfobj reserveobjnum{}
\:AtEndOfPackage{
  \let\pdfobj\:origpdfobj
  \let\pdfoutput\:origpdfoutput
  \def\PDFStructObj#1#2{}%
}
\endinput
```

The last necessary file is `accessibility.4ht`, where we can redefine commands used in the document. In this case, `\alt` was used:

```
% accessibility.4ht (2023-11-10-15:20), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2023 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2023-11-10-15:20}

\NewConfigure{accessibilityalt}{2}
\def\:tempa#1{\a:accessibilityalt #1\b:accessibilityalt}
\def\alt#1{}
\HLet\alt\:tempa

\Hinput{accessibility}
\endinput
```

This redefined version of `\alt` will print its contents in the document text, but it will show nothing in pictures. This is necessary to prevent other errors.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! It is much appreciated :D. How do you know that there will be a fix soon in TexLive?

Comment: @Locke because I've added it to tex4ht sources and the uptldates are done automatically

Comment: I don't see any reason to support the accessibility package. It is broken (also with pdflatex) and produces invalid pdf. No document should have it in their preamble. And if you want to support it: simply suppress its loading. There is no need to handle \pdfobj etc.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I originally suppressed it's loading, but I wanted to support the `\alt` command somehow, and with full suppression I ran into problems with `.4ht` files. So I found that it I can load it and just suppress the problematic code. I agree that this package shouldn't be used at all, but on the other hand I don't want novice users to run into fatal errors when they try templates that use it.

Comment: the package is 2000 lines long and contains tons of redefinitions of standard commands whose effect a novice can not really overlook. Imho you are not doing anyone a favor by keeping that running.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer OK, I will look into this, you are right